# Beginner PROOF question involving perfect squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

Let *m, n* be two positive integers. Prove that if *m, n* are perfect sqaures, then the product *mn* is also a perfect square.

So I'm not really sure where to start on that example. I assume that we can use direct proof here. I'm not sure how to write up perfect squares in formula.

Solutions?

Comment: You need to show that the product of two squares is a square. This is a multiplicative analog of the sum of two even integers is even since $\, 2j + 2k = 2(j+k).\ $ Similarly $\, j^2 k^2 = (\cdots)^2\ $

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is a perfect square, this means that there is a positive integer $k$ such that $m=k^2$. Similarly for $n$. So what can we say about $mn$?

Comment: OK so we can say that:   **_$ mn = (ab)^2$ where m = $a^2$ and n = $b^2$_**
And since **_$ mn = (ab)^2$_** is a perfect square it directly proves the statement. Or I guess you could further simplify it.

Comment: That's right, no further simplifications are needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $m$ is a perfect square means that there exists an integer $a$ such that 
$$m=a^2$$
Same way, there exists an integer $b$ so that $n=b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a perfect square $a$ is
$$a=b^2,$$

where $b$ is an integer.

So:
$$m=k^2, n=t^2,$$
their product:
$$mn=k^2t^2=(kt)^2$$

and since the product of two integers is another integer, we can let $kt=r$ and $l=r^2$.

$$mn=k^2t^2=(kt)^2=r^2=l.$$

$l$ fits the definition of a perfect square.